# Selenium, questions about code re-factoring

Tags: selenium, junit, refactoring

With `Selenium IDE` I generate a sample script for test the log to a website and a value in the website after logging. So my script is (Java) :

```
@test
public void mytest() throws Exception{
  // Load the home page 
  ...
  // complete the log form
  ...
  // check if the log work
  ...
  // Logged : click on some element in the page
  ...
  // Logged ; check the information X (if one HTML element contains child or not 
  ...
}
```

I use `JUnit` for run the test class from a main class. My question is : What is the best way for re-factoring my code ? I would like create one class by "step", is it possible ? by example :

1. Class for load page and check there isn't error 404
2. Class for complete the log form, submit and check if the user is logged
3. Class for navigate in the website and get the information I want

Is it the best way? There isn't a real goal. Just, I want know how organize the code for a maximum of reuse (sorry for my bad English x) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of reasons why you do not want to use Selenium IDE, do the recording for the test cases and refactor the code afterwards. Most of the time selenium IDE will provide you the selectors that are not stable enough. For rerunning the tests you want to make sure the selectors are stable enough and will not possibly depend on `html` structure. Second, as the test suite getting larger you want to reduce the code duplication as much as possible. Using Selenium IDE there is no way to understand which code blocks can be reused.

So, bottom line is for a good test suite start building a framework from scratch instead of using Selenium IDE. There are a lot of example out there how to start. I have one with TestNG [here](https://github.com/safrrhmn/SeleniumTestNG) if that helps.

Comment: I will follow your advices and find projects in github =)